# Developing for different screen sizes using flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-positioned

I have an app that I am going to upload to the appstore and playstore pretty soon but I am worried that it might look funny on different phone screens that vary in sizes (The app is for mobile phones only no tablets) what's the best way to code for different screen sizes using flutter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [LayoutBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) for different layout size and [OrientationBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/OrientationBuilder-class.html) for different orientation.

Check this: https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-for-multiple-screen-sizes-and-orientations-in-flutter-fragments-in-flutter-a4c51b849434

Comment: haha, I mentioned the same article. Your answer is no different from mine.

Comment: I guess, we answered at the same time :) coincidence

Answer (score 3):

You use `MediaQuery` for size determination.

And `OrientationBuilder` for orientation of the device.

[Here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-for-multiple-screen-sizes-and-orientations-in-flutter-fragments-in-flutter-a4c51b849434) is a nice article you might want to read.